# Inappbrowser window.open not working (visual studio 2015)

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

I'm trying to open a website using inappbrowser in my test project on VS2015 (cordova 6). In the index.html file, I have added:-

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_self', 'location=yes');">Google Search</a>
```

In config.xml, I have this:-

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" version="1.3.1-dev" src="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" />
```

Somehow, when I click the link, nothing happens. It's like inappbrowser doesn't respond. Could this be whitelist issues?

Config.xml already allow:

```
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

Previously when I was using Cordova 3.0, it works fine.

Some help on this would be wonderful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you aware that Phonegap is not a [webserver or a webbrowser](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005)? Are you aware that both [Google and Apple frown on apps](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005a) that are website wrappers?

Answer (score 0):

Apache team changed the plugin functions as the below link :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Try to use the official site to review plugin changes .

So instead of your code use :

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have also tried using var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open (url, target, options); but still couldn't open url.

Maybe I have to download plugin as per-your suggestion? It looks like plugin wasn't running at all.

Comment: Try download the latest version and install it locally.